# Can't figure out how to render 2D in lwjgl

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to switch from using JFrame from a 2D game to using lwjgl for performance reasons. I added lwjgl and I am brand new to using it and the rendering just seems completely broken. I initialize everything properly but when I try to draw a simple rectangle on the screen I use a drawQuads method I found on google and it seems just broken like none of the values do what they are supposed to, I can't put the x and y coordinates in since the screen seems to render very small values like -0.8 to 0.8 and since I used JFrame I just used the pixel coordinates like 200,400. How do I fix this, what am I doing wrong? This is the main class that renders and ticks everything and right now it just renders a broken rectangle in the render method.

```
private void lwjglInit() {
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();
        if (!glfwInit())
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
        // Configure GLFW
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, title, NULL, NULL);
        if ( window == NULL )
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the rendering loop
        });

        try ( MemoryStack stack = stackPush() ) {
            IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1);
            IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1);

            // Get the window size passed to glfwCreateWindow
            glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);

            // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
            GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

            // Center the window
            glfwSetWindowPos(
                window,
                (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
            );
        }
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        // Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);
        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(window);
        
        GL.createCapabilities();
        
        // Set the clear color
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    private void init() {
        handler = new Handler();
        input = new KeyInput();
        new Camera(0, 0);
        level = new Level(this, handler);
        handler.setLevel(level);
        minput = new MouseInput(this);
//      this.addKeyListener(input);
//      this.addMouseListener(minput);
//      this.addMouseMotionListener(minput);
        screen = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }
    private synchronized void start() {
        if (isRunning)
            return;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        isRunning = true;
    }
    private synchronized void stop() {
        if (!(isRunning))
            return;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        isRunning = false;
        // Free the window callbacks and destroy the window
        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }
    public void run() {
        lwjglInit();
        init();
        
        level.load("res/levels/default/level1.png");
        
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int updates = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        while(isRunning) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            render();
            frames++;
                    
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " TICKS: " + updates);
                frames = 0;
                updates = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }
    private void tick() {
        if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            isRunning = false;
            return;
        }
        glfwPollEvents();
        handler.tick();
        Camera.tick();
    }
    private void render() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        Renderer.drawQuad(-0.7, 0, 0.3, 0.3, 255, 0, 0);
        
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        }
```

And this is the render method for the drawQuads:

```
    public static void drawQuad(double x, double y, double width, double height, int red, int green, int blue) {
        GL11.glColor3f(red, green, blue);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glVertex2f((float)-x, (float)y);
        glVertex2f((float)width, (float)y);
        glVertex2f((float)width, (float)-height);
        glVertex2f((float)-x, (float)-height);

        glEnd();
    }
```

I try putting different values for x or y and it seems to just stretch the rectangle, if I try to change the width and height it just moves it or stretches it.

Comment: Your drawQuads method doesnt work likely because glBegin and glEnd are depreciated. You need to use buffers now to store vertex information. GL_QUADS primitive is also depreciated, youll need to use GL_TRIANGLE or GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS to draw quads